# How do I make symlink to Desktop work correctly at startup on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: mount, startup, symbolic-link

I have symlinks to Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Music, and Videos which link to a second hard drive.  I am mounting the other hard drive through /etc/fstab.  All the links work on start up, but it must be mounting the other drive after setting the desktop, because the view of the desktop reverts to the /home/user folder.  (Symbolic link of desktop still goes to other drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  The first time I restarted I hadn't entered the mount commands in fstab correctly.  I had them as:

```
/dev/sdX pathtomounteddirectory
```

where the X is the proper suffix. (I used `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` in terminal to edit the fstab folder, and `df -h` to find the proper suffix and the pathtomounteddirectory.)

I had changed the fstab commands to:

```
/dev/sdX pathtomounteddirectory ext4 defaults 0 0
```

I verified the filesystem type using `parted -l`.

Anyways, my initial error had changed my `user-dirs.dirs` file found in my `.config` folder under my Home directory.  (You can make it visible using `ctrl + h` outside terminal or using `ls -a` inside terminal).  Once I reedited my `user-dirs.dirs` file, everything worked fine.