# Desktop Link will be broken after restart

Tags: 12.04, .desktop

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I want to create a link from the `WorkSpace` folder on my desktop.

I did right click on that folder and choose `Make Link` option from the menu. And did move/paste or copy/past that link on the desktop, but...

When I perform system restart, the link is broken.

So, is it possible to create a link from a folder that is in `E:\`, on the desktop, without creating a helper link as known from windows "send to" functionality?

Comment: I am on ubuntu 16.04 and the way you tried to create and move a folder link to desktop works fine. This is the only way to graphically create a link I know of. BTW I recommend updating your ubuntu OS to the latest LTS version, because for 12.04 hardware support has ended. [EndOfLife] (https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)

Comment: The above said way works for me until not restarting. After that the moved link will broken.

Comment: Ubuntu OS has no drive letter `E:\` for optical ROM... I am sorry for my formatting, mini-Markdown is not working for me...

Comment: The appropriated drive letter is `Archive`. That drive is not optical. So there is a folder in my `Archive` Partition on HDD, which I need create a link on the desktop.

Comment: do you mount your drive partition on startup via fstab?

Comment: @Leder, No. I have not done this, and know how doing. The drive has NTFS file system.

Comment: see the answers given! And google or ask for fstab and mount.

Comment: As mentioned by Leder, there are no drive letters in Ubuntu... Or any Linux/UNIX OS, for that matter. Please do check the answers and follow the instructions to have your drive mount at boot by editing /etc/fstab. It would also be very helpful to include some more information, such as where your 'WorkSpace' directory is specifically. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get a broken link is that the host partition is not mounted on startup. You have to add the UUID of that partition to `/ets/fstab`.

[This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup) will help you to get your correct UUID.

Comment: If the disk is slow that might not be enough. External disks and internal windows disk tend to be slow as is.

Comment: @Rinzwind There's a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1111233/301745) about a network disk. If you have a solution or any suggestions, I'm sure OP would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this answer [fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479291/how-do-i-make-symlink-to-desktop-work-correctly-at-startup-on-ubuntu-14-04) for automounting in `/etc/fstab` and beware of filesystem type, e. g. ext4 or ntfs or similar, and device name...